# WebForms with Entity Framework without DI. How I should use and dispose context?

Tags: entity-framework, webforms

I would like to use the legacy Web Forms technology with Entity Framework.
I can't use Dependency Injection.
I would like use 3 layers ( Pages, BL and DAL )
I'd like to release unmanaged resources.
So...Does this code make sense ? (I'm just putting here just parts, but I believe it is clear)

My questions:

Do I have to use "using" to dispose services and dbContext?
My page use 2 different services. I want to use one context per request

Maybe there is a better way?

2 different services:

```
using DomainApp.Services.Contracts;
using DomainApp.DTOS;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;

namespace DomainApp.Services
{
    public class UserService : IUserService, IDisposable
    {
        private DomainAppContext _context { get; set; }
        public UserService(DomainAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public User GetUserByName(string userName)
        {
            using (var context = new DomainAppContext())
            {
                return context.Users
                    .Include(x => x.UserRoles.Select(y => y.Role))
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == userName);
            }
        }

        /*disposable*/
        private bool disposed = false;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

second service

```
    using DomainApp.DTOS;
    using DomainApp.Services.Contracts;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    
    namespace DomainApp.Services
    {
        public class TaskItemService : ITaskItemService, IDisposable
        {
            private DomainAppContext _context { get; set; }
            public TaskItemService(DomainAppContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            
            public IList<TaskItem> GetTaskItemsByUserId(int userId)
            {
                return _context.TaskItems
                    .Include(x => x.Status)
                    .Include(x => x.TaskType)
                    .Where(x=>x.UserId==userId).ToList();
            }
    
            /*disposable*/
            private bool disposed = false;
            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!this.disposed)
                {
                    if (disposing)
                    {
                        _context.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
    
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
}
```

page (aspx.cs file )

```
using DomainApp;
using DomainApp.DTOS;
using DomainApp.Services;
using DomainApp.Services.Contracts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace AdvancedWebFormApp.Pages
{
    public partial class Task : Page
    {
        public IList<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }

        private IUserService _userService;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _appContext = new DomainAppContext();
            using (var _userService = new UserService(_appContext))
            {
                var cookie = this.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

                var roles = ticket.UserData.Split('|').ToList();
                if (!roles.Contains("User"))
                {
                    this.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    var user = _userService.GetUserByName(ticket.Name);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        using(var _taskItemService = new TaskItemService(_appContext))
                        {
                            TaskItems = _taskItemService.GetTaskItemsByUserId(user.UserId);
                        }     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TaskItems = new List<TaskItem>();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you might not have, or know you have a Dependency Injection provider, your services are using dependency inversion. (or Inversion of Control) They are accepting a DbContext in their constructor, so I'm a bit confused why you say you "cannot use DI"?

Dependency Inversion is a pattern by which code receives dependencies rather than instantiating them in-line. This allows those dependencies to be substituted. Dependency Injection is the process by which those dependencies are injected. In your case, how are these services being constructed and provided with a DbContext? (_context) Your main form code doesn't look like it would compile as you are declaring a module level variable for the service, then attempting to scope an instance using a `using(var _userService = new UserService(_appContext))`. The DbContext instance being scoped in your Page Load is definitely not the right way to scope a DbContext to be shared across services.

It is actually quite easy to set up dependency injection in a Webforms application, even if an existing web application has no DI set up, it is something that you can gradually roll out through an application. It doesn't have to be replaced all at once. For a start I recommend having a look at Autofac. (https://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/integration/webforms.html) Autofac is an IoC Container that works across pretty much any .Net application type. It is well documented and a common solution to find examples and help with.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer.
I don't want use DI it doesn't mean I can't use DI.
I used DI (Structuremap in MVC projects) so I know a bit about the subject.

But .. In my question, I was more concerned with understanding Dispose.  If I don't use DbContext directly from the Page level, but by calls services (userService, taskItemService), then am I not released unmanaged resources? And 2nd point.
 If I use page with two services based on the same database, is it better to create 2 dbContexts or 1 and use it in both services. Good way is have one dbContext per request.